# Php Mysql Student Rank

Tags: mysql

[image: database]

I have this data in my database, all i want to do is to get the rank position and ties of student in a class based on the there total score , subject, session and term
i tried this but getting different position

```
SELECT  d.username, c.ranks FROM
     (   SELECT   total_score, @rank:=@rank+1 Ranks   FROM 
          (SELECT  DISTINCT total_score FROM
                   cbt_result a  ORDER BY total_score DESC) t,    
          (SELECT @rank:= 0) r )
          c  INNER JOIN cbt_result d 
          ON c.total_score = d.total_score 
     WHERE term = 'first'  
AND  class_id ='$key' 
AND subject_id = '$subkey' 
AND username ='$student_username' 
AND session_term = '$session_term_key'
```

Comment: So what happens with this code currently? Is there PHP usage you are having an issue with or just the query?

Comment: Show your expected results. The question is vague.

Comment: From the above code ,  am expecting to get 1st - 5th positions of student because i have 5 student in that class but now am getting 8th , 16th and so other position

Comment: Create a sqlfiddle with your data, and show a text table of desired results. See [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899464). No one cares about your picture btw. Pictures do nothing for us.